# How to exclude file on maven release:prepare and release:perform?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven to release/tag my projects, and I am using some propery files and want mvn:prepare to exclude those under release. I tried using the following command:

```
mvn release:prepare -DpreparationGoals="clean install"
-DcheckModificationExcludeList=props.properties
```

But it still gives me the following error:

```
[INFO] Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
[props.properties:unknown]
```

So the question is: how can ACTUALLY make maven mvn:release skip checking for certian local modifications? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first question which comes to my mind is: Why not correctly removing files you don't need or put them on the ignore (.gitignore or svn:ignore property)? Sounds a little bit strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was implemented in version **2.1**

Comment: Can you explain how to make it ignore the files?