# Remove files on mvn release:prepare

Tags: maven, release, pom.xml

I have some files that I only need for local development, and do not want to be packaged up in a release.

How can I add an automatic step to the POM so that it removes files when I do a `mvn release:prepare`?

Answer (score 1):

If the files for local development are in a self contained module then you can pass an -N flag.

Source - http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html

or look at [How to exclude file on maven release:prepare and release:perform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833584/how-to-exclude-file-on-maven-releaseprepare-and-releaseperform)

If you are using version 2.1 or higher.

Comment: And then if I wanted to not include some files in the release, would that depend on the 'delegated package' that handles the release? Or does Maven handle releasing in its core? I'm not sure how the actual release cycle happens...? Any pointers for good reading material?

Comment: There isn't much on reading material for the release cycle other than the plug-in FAQ and http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html that I could find. But you're right, it does depend on the delegated package that handles it. You could use `checkModificationExcludeList` with `mvn release:prepare -DcheckModificationExcludeList=file.txt,file.txt`